# Custom hibernate.cfg.xml location on a KARAF OSGI Bundle

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi, karaf

I need to configure hibernate to load the hibernate.cfg.xml  from a custom location on an OSGI bundle on karaf. I need to be able to edit the configuration without editing the JAR file which seems to be the only option available. I am using the following class to load the Hibernate SessionFactory as described on the hibernate documentation, but it seems there are no way to configure this on the SessionFactory returned by the Hibernate OSGI module exposing this service. I have been researching this problem several days but I can not find a solution. I am using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final.  Any help is very much appreciated, Thanks

public class HibernateUtil {

```
private static SessionFactory sf;

public static Session getSession() {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}

private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if ( sf == null ) {
        Bundle thisBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle( HibernateUtil.class );

        BundleContext context = thisBundle.getBundleContext();

        ServiceReference sr = context.getServiceReference( SessionFactory.class.getName() );
        sf = (SessionFactory) context.getService( sr );
    }
    return sf;
}
```

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final

Answer (score 1):

After many days of work and following many different leads I was able to solve the problem. The main idea was to store the database connection properties outside the hibernate.cfg.xml file which has to be inside the jar file for Hibernate OSGI to find it. In the contrary the properties file can be located anywhere you like. To accomplish this define a JNDI service using blueprint, then config the JNDI service on the hibernate.cfg.xml  with the following tag:

```
<property name="connection.datasource">osgi:service/jdbc/mysqlds</property>
```

The code to define the JNDI service with blueprint is the following:

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
      <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClass}"/>
      <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
      <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
     </bean>


 <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
  <service-properties>
   <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/mysqlds"/>
   <entry key="datasource.name" value="MySqlDS"/>
  </service-properties>
 </service>
```

it is important to mention that I tried using many different DataSource classes which usually fail with a classnotfound error. The only that worked for me was SimpleDriverDataSource